# When to instantiate object in this situation?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have been stumbling over an annoyance of this form several times, so my question is: What is the best pattern/practice for code scenarios as below?

Here is an example of a method body I wrote recently:

```
public HashSet<char> SomeCharacters(IEnumerable<string> _hashes){

    HashSet<char> Result = new HashSet<char>();
    bool _firstpass = true;

    foreach (string _hash in _hashes) {
        if (_firstpass) {
            Result = new HashSet<char>(_hash);
            _firstpass = false;
        }
        else {
            // ...
            // some code that uses Result
        }
    }
    return Result;
}
```

This works fine, but what's annoying me is the first line

`HashSet<char> Result = new HashSet<char>();`

which I'd instinctively like to replace by `HashSet<char> Result;`. The compiler won't let me, because the `else` block uses `Result` which it does not recognize as instanciated, although I know it will be by the time the `else` block is executed.

The way above forces me to create `Result` twice, which is not good for many reasons (performance, code aesthetics, ...).

Please consider this question a question about scenarios like this, not only focussed on this particular example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refactor to remove the flag:

```
public HashSet<char> SomeCharacters(IEnumerable<string> _hashes){

    string first = _hashes.FirstOrDefault();
    if(first == null) return new HashSet<char>();

    HashSet<char> Result = new HashSet<char>(first);

    foreach (string _hash in _hashes.Skip(1)) {
        // ...
        // some code that uses Result
    }
    return Result;
}
```

You will need to be sure that it is safe to enumerate `_hashes` more than once however.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean exactly by '... be sure it is safe to ...'? In the first enumeration, `_hashes` is not being manipulated, so why should it not be safe?

Comment: @ToaoG - An enumerator for `_hashes` is being fetched twice in this code - once for `FirstOrDefault` and the second in the `foreach` loop. When given an `IEnumerable<T>` you may only be able to enumerate it once - if it is a wrapper over a forward-only stream for example. If `_hashes` is an in-memory collection then you can enumerate it as many times as you want. I was pointing out that this is a subtle change to the behaviour of the original function.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Didn't come to mind that you could use it a s a wrapper on a stream.

Answer (score 5):

Just assign `null` to the variable initially:

```
HashSet<char> Result = null;
```

You can then also get rid of the `_firstpass` variable:

```
HashSet<char> Result = null;
foreach (string _hash in _hashes) {
    if (Result == null) {
        Result = new HashSet<char>(_hash);
    }
    else {
        // ...
        // some code that uses Result
    }
}
```

If the only purpose of iterating the collection of strings is to put all the characters of the strings in a `HashSet<char>` then you can do it simply like this:

```
var Result = new HashSet<char>(_hashes.SelectMany(s => s));
```

The principle here is that sometimes you can rewrite loops with "first pass create and add" logic into much simpler LINQ statements where you build the sequence and then create the final object using `ToList` or in this case the `HashSet` constructor.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the boolean variable be left out, well, this assumes the `else` block never assignes `null` to `Result`. ..

Comment: ... and no, that's not at all the only purpose, but thanks anyway. Like I said in the question, it was more about problems of similar nature not this one in particular

Comment: @ToaoG: Yes. Your question seems to indicate the `Result` is used in the else block, not cleared, but if that is the case then you cannot get rid of `_firstpass`.